# Linux: how to connect to WIFI router via WPS?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I'm using xubuntu. I don't see any option to connect to my router via WPS. Is this possible at all?

Comment: WPS is not secure.  Its very likely the feature was remvoe or was never supported by your router

Comment: **Do not** use WPS - [just Google "is wps flawed"](https://www.google.com/search?q=is+wps+flawed).

Comment: I agree that WPS shouldn't be used, but since it's a widespread technology we should be able to use it. Even if you don't use it on your network, sometimes you wanto to be able it anyway. For example in places where the network owner doesn't know/remember the wifi password and relies on WPS to let her/his guests connect to local network (I've seen this in a small school).